# Difference between sudo -i and sudo su

Tags: sudo, command, su

What is the difference between `sudo -i` and `sudo su`?

Comment: To be fair, while _answers_ to the linked question address "sudo su", it was not part of the original linked question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on the descriptions from the man pages for `su` and `sudo` I would assume the following things:

1. Since `sudo -iu <user>` means a login shell this would be equivalent to an `su - <user>` or `su -l <user>`.
2. An `su` without any arguments changes your effective user ID but you're still using your original `<user>` environment and a `who am i` will report you're still `<user>`.

*excerpt sudo man page*

```
-i [command]
        The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified in
        the passwd(5) entry of the target user as a login shell.  This means
        that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will 
        be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to 
        the shell for execution.  Otherwise, an interactive shell is 
        executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory 
        before running the shell.  It also initializes the environment, 
        leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged, setting HOME, MAIL, SHELL, 
        USER, LOGNAME, and PATH, as well as the contents of 
        /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems.  All other environment 
        variables are removed.
```

#### Example

I have a user account, `saml` with a UID of 500.

```
$ egrep "Uid|Gid" /proc/$$/task/$$/status
Uid:    500 500 500 500
Gid:    501 501 501 501
```

In the above output, the 1st column is my real UID (uid) and the 2nd is my effective UID (euid).

#### Becoming root via (su)

```
$ su
```

Now I'm root, but I still maintain my environment and my real UID is still `500`. Notice that my euid is now 0 (root).

```
$ egrep "Uid|Gid" /proc/$(pgrep su -n)/task/$(pgrep su -n)/status
Uid:    500 0   0   0
Gid:    501 501 501 501
```

However my environment is still `saml`'s. Here's one of he environment variables, `$LOGNAME`.

```
$ env | grep LOGNAME
LOGNAME=saml
```

#### Becoming root via (su -) or (sudo -i)

```
$ su -
```

With an `su -` or `sudo -i` not only do I change my effective UID to a new user, but I also source their files as if it was a login, and my environment now becomes identical as if I were them directly logging in.

```
$ egrep "Uid|Gid" /proc/$(pgrep su -n)/task/$(pgrep su -n)/status
Uid:    500 0   0   0
Gid:    501 501 501 501
```

However my environment is now `root`'s. Same variable, `$LOGNAME`, now it's set with `root`.

```
$ env | grep LOGNAME
LOGNAME=root
```

#### So then what's the difference?

Well let's try the above with `sudo -i` and find out.

```
$ sudo -i
```

Now let's look at the same info:

```
$ egrep "Uid|Gid" /proc/$(pgrep su -n)/task/$(pgrep su -n)/status
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    501 501 501 501
```

Well one major thing is my effective ID and real ID are both 0 (`root`) with this approach. The environment variable `$LOGNAME` is as if we logged in as `root`.

```
$ env | grep LOGNAME
LOGNAME=root
```

#### Comparing environments

If we count the number of lines in say the 3 methods, perhaps there is some additional info to be had.

```
$ env > /tmp/<method used to become root>
```

We are left with these 3 files:

- -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1999 Nov  2 06:43 sudo_root.txt
- -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1970 Nov  2 06:44 sudash_root.txt
- -rw-r--r--  1 root root   4859 Nov  2 06:44 su_root.txt

Already we can see that something is up with just a plain `su`. The env. is over 2x the size of the others.

Number of lines in each:

```
$ wc -l su*
  28 sudash_root.txt
  32 sudo_root.txt
  92 su_root.txt
```

There's really no need to look further at the `su_root.txt` file. This file contains a much of user's environment that ran the `su` command. So let's look at the other 2 files.

They're virtually identical except for a few cosmetic variables, such as `$LANG` being slightly different. The one smoking gun in the list is the `$PATH`.

*sudo*

```
 PATH=/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/brlcad/bin:/root/bin
```

*su -*

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/brlcad/bin:/root/bin
```

As you can see `sudo -i` gives us some additional protection by stripping out suspicious paths, but it also keeps our `$DISPLAY` and `$TERM` intact in case we were displaying a GUI to  different location.

#### Takeaways?

1. The big takeaway is that the method used to become root `sudo -i` has advantages over the others because you use your own password to do so, protecting root's password from needing to be given out.
2. There is logging when you became `root`, vs. mysteriously someone becoming `root` via `su` or `su -`.
3. `sudo -i` gives you a better user experience over either `su` because it protects your `$DISPLAY` and `$TERM`.
4. `sudo -i` provides some protection to the system when users become `root`, by limiting the environment which they are given.

#### What about `sudo su` - you didn't even discuss it?

I intentionally avoided bringing that into the discussion even though the OP asked about it because doing so would only have confused the issue, IMO. When you run `sudo su` the `sudo` command masks the effects of the `su` and so much of the environment that you'd get from a regular `su` is lost. Sudo is doing its job and providing a limited and protected environment regardless of whether it's `sudo su` or `sudo -i`.

#### Example

Here's the result of the `sudo su` environment being dumped:

```
ls -l /tmp/sudosu_root.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1933 Nov  2 14:48 /tmp/sudosu_root.txt
```

And the number of lines:

```
$ wc -l /tmp/sudosu_root.txt 
31 /tmp/sudosu_root.txt
```

These are the only variables that differ between a `sudo su -` and a `sudo -i`:

```
$ sdiff /tmp/sudosu_root.txt /tmp/sudo_root.txt  | grep ' |'
USERNAME=saml                             | USERNAME=root
PATH=/usr/lib64/ccache:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/brl | PATH=/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/saml                 | MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PWD=/home/saml/tst                        | PWD=/root
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su                      | SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
XAUTHORITY=/root/.xauthYFtlL3             | XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-saml-iZePuv/datab
```

So as you can see there really isn't much of a difference between them. Slightly different `$PATH`, the `$SUDO_COMMAND`, and the `$MAIL` and `$USERNAME` are the only differences.

#### References

- [Real and Effective IDs](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/083)

Comment: both `sudo` and `su` go through the PAM stack. If it logs under one, it should be logging under the other. Also `sudo su` will strip the environment just like `sudo -i` will. In fact I don't see you mention `sudo su` anywhere in your answer...

Comment: @Patrick - figured it was long enough already. I figured touching on `sudo -i` was sufficient in giving insights into the advantages of `sudo` over bare `su -`. Do you think it's necessary to mention it? I'll mention that I've been on Solaris systems that did not log `su` attempts but did log `sudo`, so that distinction though a low possibility is possible.

Comment: No, I was referring to you covering "bare `su`". Op asked about `sudo su`, not `su` :-)

Comment: @Patrick - that was intentional not to discuss `sudo su`. Since the `sudo` that prefixes would've masked the effects of `su`. Most ppl get lost in the `.bashrc` & `.profile` business so I was attempting to shield the OP from that morass and cut to the effect, which is the resulting environment.

Comment: @Patrick - Added `sudo su` to the descriptions (at the end).

Answer (score 12):

I think @slm misread the question, so providing another answer.

He did hit on the main point, about one being a login shell and the other not.
When running `sudo -i` the shell will become a login shell, and so it will read things like `~/.profile` where as a non-login shell will only read `~/.bashrc`.

When chaining `sudo` with `su` (as in `sudo su`), neither the `sudo` nor the `su` invoke a login shell. The equivalent to `sudo -i` when using `su` would instead be `sudo su -l`.

I personally consider `sudo su` to be along the lines of "useless use of cat" examples. You can get the same behavior with `sudo -s`.

There are basically 5 common ways of invoking a root shell via sudo

- `sudo su`

  - non-login shell
  - sets `HOME` to `/root`
  - Prunes the environment
- `sudo -i`

  - login shell
  - sets `HOME` to `/root`
  - Prunes the environment
- `sudo su -l`

  - login shell
  - sets `HOME` to `/root`
  - Prunes the environment

  *When invoking a shell, this is equivalent to `sudo -i`*
- `sudo -s`

  - non-login shell
  - sets `HOME` to `/root`
  - Prunes the environment

  *When invoking a shell, this is equivalent to `sudo su`*
- `sudo -Es`

  - non-login shell
  - Leaves `HOME` alone
  - Leaves the environment alone (except for `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` iirc)

---

Note, that these rules only apply when using them to gain a shell. There is a difference between `sudo -s somecommand` and `sudo su -c somecommand`.

Answer (score 3):

The second one preserves the current directory (pwd) but the first command drops the user to the root's home directory.